# Generic overloaded method resolution problems

Tags: c#

I have two methods with these signatures:

```
void Method<T>(T data)
{
}

void Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
}
```

Its an overload of the same method to take either a single object or a list of them. If I try to pass a List<'T> to it, it resolves to the first method, when obviosly i want the second. I have to use list.AsEnumerable() to get it to resolve to the second. Is there any way to make it resolve to the second regardless of whether the list is type T[], IList<'T>, List<'T>, Collection<'T>, IEnumerable<'T>, etc.

Comment: What is the point of the first method?

Comment: "when obviosly i want the second" - obvious to whom? How is the compiler supposed to make the distinction?

Comment: @Oded: By the rules of its overload resolution mechanism, of course.

Comment: You could use `Method<int>(data)` (explicitly specifying `T`). It is probably not what you want as well. Loose the first method and it will work well (instead turn it to more overloads).

Comment: But I can I do this with just second method?

SomeData data = new SomeData();
whatever.Method(data);

Comment: Does the second method apply the first to all items in the `IEnumerable`, by any chance? In that case, lose the second method, and use a `foreach` loop at the call site instead.

Comment: @user380689: It mostly depends on what you are trying to do inside the method. The `Method` should execute some common operations on the passed parameter.

Comment: @Vash: `Method<U> (U data)` would collide with `Method<T>(T data)`.

Comment: What if I wish to call `Method` on a list and then on the contents of a list?  These two separate calls both need to use a different version of `Method`.  Follow Eric Lippert's advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution: **do not go there in the first place**. This is a *bad design*. You'll note that none of the framework classes do this. A list has two methods: Add, and AddRange. The first adds a single item, the second adds a sequence of items.

It's a bad design because *you are writing a device for automatically producing bugs*. Consider again the example of a mutable list:

```
List<object> myqueries = new List<object>();
myqueries.Add(from c in customers select c.Name);
myqueries.Add(from o in orders where o.Amount > 10000.00m select o);
```

You'd expect that to add two queries to the list of queries; if Add were overloaded to take a sequence then *this would add the query results to the list, not the queries.*  You need to be able to distinguish between a *query* and its *results*; they are logically completely different.

The best thing to do is to make the methods have two different names.

If you're hell bent on this bad design, then *if it hurts when you do that, don't do that*. Overload resolution is designed to find the *best possible match*. Don't try to hammer on overload resolution so that it does something *worse*. Again, that is confusing and bug prone. *Solve the problem using some other mechanism.* For example:

```
static void Frob(IEnumerable ts) // not generic!
{
    foreach(object t in ts) Frob<object>(t);
}
static void Frob<T>(T t)
{
    if (t is IEnumerable)
        Frob((IEnumerable) t);
    else
        // otherwise, frob a single T.
}
```

Now no matter what the user gives you - an array of T, an array of lists of T, whatever, you end up only frobbing single Ts.

But again, this is *almost certainly a bad idea*. Don't do it.  Two methods that have *different semantics* should have *different names*.

Comment: System.Xml.Linq classes **do** use this design. Methods like `XElement.Add()` accept `object`, `object[]`, and (in some instances) `IEnumerable`. Arguably, the semantics of adding a single child element vs. multiple child elements are the same - but such an argument could be extended to `List.Add()` as well then. In general, I agree that methods that do different things should have different names - I just think that in some cases it is nuanced, and deciding whether two operations are truly different isn't always obvious. But, in this case, I tend to agreew with your response to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you are doing this:

```
var list = new List<Something>();
Method<List<Something>>(list); // Will resolve to the first overload.
```

Or:

```
var list = new List<Something>();
Method<Something>(list); // Will resolve to the second overload.
```

The reason this occurs, is the compiler will select the most specific method it can, so where your generic `Method<T>(T data)` is used, it is compiled as `Method<List<Something>>(List<Something> data)`, which is more specific than `IEnumerable<Something>`

Answer (score 1):

The overload resolution will attempt to find the *best* matching overload.

In the case of the `IEnumerable<T>` overload, you will indeed need to explicitly convert or use the `IEnumerable<T>`, as then that will indeed be the best match.

Otherwise, the simple generic overload will be considered a better match.

For a lot more detail, read the ["overload resolution"](https://ericlippert.com/category/overload-resolution/) blog entries of Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat unusual to have overloads such that a method can take either a single thing, or a collection of things, isn't it? Why not just have

```
void MethodSingle<T>(T data)
{
    Method(new T[] { data });
}

void Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
}
```

Clearer to both the compiler and the reader, I'd suggest.

Comment: +1: It's much clearer not to use overloads in this case. No infinite loop here.

Comment: @Jaroslav please explain. This code compiles and runs as expected. Note that this is *instead of* the code in the question (ie the original `Method(T data)` no longer exists)

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the `MethodSingle`, saw `Method` instead. Anyway, it still does not solve anything, on the contrary - it makes it worse. You would be enumerating an array with a single item. In case of a `List<X>` it would enumerate over `List<X>[]`, not over the expected `List<X>`!

Comment: @Jaroslav sorry, I don't understand what you mean. When you have a single item, you call `MethodSingle`; when you have a list, you call `Method`.

Comment: It is probably the names of the methods that make it bad. If it were `Add` and `AddRange` for example, it would make much more sense => `MethodSingle` and `MethodMultiple`. Also calling `MethodSingle` in `MethodMultiple` (not the other way around) makes much more sense. Also he may even have a different logic to do in both cases which would indicate the names should be different anyway. The **names** of methods really DO matter (that's what I meant).

Answer (score 0):

Q:

> Is there any way to make it resolve to the second regardless of whether the list is type T[], IList<'T>, List<'T>, Collection<'T>, IEnumerable<'T>, etc.

The T[] is not an list but an array, so probably no.

I not sure that this will be helpful but you can try to create a method with restrictions

```
public void Method<U,T> (U date) where U : IList<T> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: It does not solve anything. The first overload will still be called as it is the best match.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't expand the method this way:

```
void Method<T>(T data)
{
    var enumerable = data as IEnumerable<T>;
    if(enumerable != null)
    {
        Method(enumerable);
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: For a `List<X>` it would do: `var enumerable = data as IEnumerable<List<X>>`.