# Strange behavior from function overload resolution in c# with generics

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I've the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(new List<int>());
        Foo(10.3);
        Foo((IList<int>)new List<int>());
    }

    static void Foo<T>(IList<T> list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo'List: {0}", typeof(T));
    }

    static void Foo<T>(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo'T: {0}", typeof(T));
    }
}
```

when executing the result is

```
Foo'T: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
Foo'T: System.Double
Foo'List: System.Int32
```

it is strange that the first call done to `Foo<T>(T)` and not `Foo<T>(IList<T>)` even though `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`.

Comment: Not really. When attempting to resolve which overload is most suitable, the compiler will only walk the inheritance tree if no suitable overload is present on first pass. In this instance there is, just not the one you think it should use.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3310227/284240 In E.Lippert's words: "don't go there, it's a bad design because you are writing a device for automatically producing bugs". Instead use different method names like the framework also does(`List<T>.Add` and `List<T>.AddRange`).